# How to change context value in functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-functional-component

I have a context named `StatusContext` like this:

```
export const statusCtxInit = {
    open: false,
    toggleOpen() {
        this.open = !this.open;
    }
};

const StatusContext = React.createContext(statusCtxInit);
export default StatusContext
```

The whole app is wrapping with the provider:

```
// ...
<StatusContext.Provider value={statusCtxInit}>
// ...
```

To use the values of my context I use `useContext` in my FC and it works when I get the value.

```
function MyComp() {
    const status = useContext(StatusContext);
    return (
        <div>
            {status.open
                ? `It's Open`
                : `It's Closed`}

            <button onClick={() => status.toggleOpen()}>
                Toggle
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyComp
```

On the other hand, I also want to change the context by calling the `toggleOpen` but, it does not work as I want. Actually the value changes but not effect the `MyComp`.

What I did wrong? What shall I do?

Comment: `statusCtxInit ` is not a React stateful component

Comment: @DennisVash I can not realize what you write. yes, It's just a simple object

Comment: @gaditzkhori I can not realize what you write. yes, It's just a simple object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```react
import React from 'react';

const statusContext = React.createContext();
const {Provider} = statusContext;
// custom provider
export const StatusProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = React.useState(false)
  const toggle = () => setOpen(v => !v)
  return (
    <Provider value={{isOpen, toggle}}>
      {children}
    </Provider>
  )
}

//custom hook
export const useStatus = () => React.useContext(StatusContext)

//usage
function MyComp() {
  const status = useStatus()
  return (
    <div>
      {status.isOpen
        ? `It's Open`
        : `It's Closed`}

      <button onClick={() => status.toggle()}>
        Toggle
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyComp
```